# How to Overwrite a variable in makefile from terminal

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, multiple-makefiles

I have created a simple makefile i.e.

```
COMMON=hello
all:
  gcc $(COMMON).c -o $(COMMON).o
```

The directory in which I am running the makefile contains three files: hello.c add.c multiply.c factorial.c and subtraction.c.

When I am compiling this in the terminal using the `make` command, the hello gets printed. Now I want to make changes in the program such that when I write "make add" or "make multiply" or "make factorial", the corresponding program will compile.

Answer (score 3):

Just supply it on the command line.

```
make COMMON=bye
```

If the target is predictable from file names in the current directory, you don't really need a Makefile at all, because Make already knows how to make `multiply` from `multiply.c`.

```
.PHONY: all
all: hello add multiply factorial
```

If you really want an explicit recipe, try something like this.

```
%: %.c
        gcc -o $@ $^
```

Comment: this thing i already know.......but if the user dont know "COMMON" is there in the file.............the user just want to use "make <filename>" to compile the program....